# Slow Migration is it possible with a PHP/SQL Driven site

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, migration, sql

I have a Joomla site that is operating on `www.mysite.com`, I want to migrate to WordPress but heres the thing, I have hundreds of pages and simply moving migrating them to a `test site` isn't ideal since well I want to migrate now.. but I don't have the time to change all the pages all at once.

Now I already know its possible to install the WordPress to `www.mysite.com/wordpress/` but obviously at a later date but this is not very ideal because due to the sheer number of undesirable redirects at an later stage.

My question is fairly simple but may require a complex answer.

Is it possible to run 2 SQL Driven sites in PHP such as Joomla and WordPress in the same Directory.. i.e `www.mysite.com/` if so how.. and if not why not! I understand this might because of the `index.php` but is there a way around this perhaps via .htaccess - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How To Change Wordpress index.php Name](http://journalxtra.com/websiteadvice/change-index-php-wordpress-4576/#Change_the_Name_of_indexphp)

This should answer your last question. I think this would let you run Wordpress and Joomla out of the same directory, but you have to keep in mind that they will likely be sharing an htaccess file which can get messy and also if you are using permalinks things might be even trickier.

1. Open .htaccess file of the root site for editing
2. Change every instance of index.php to blog.php
3. Change every instance of index.php to blog.php to blog.php
4. Add the directive DirectoryIndex blog.php index.php to the very top of .htaccess
5. Save and close .htaccess.
6. Rename index.php to blog.php

Before making any changes to your live site be sure to back up all files and databases. I would probably recommend trying this out in a test directory first and see how the run side by side. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't run both on the same folder.

Install WP on a separate folder, copy as fast as you can, adjust all URLs (to keep SEO), and then flip the switch (replace one site with the other).

I have been doing migrations for more than 6 years now, and rushing a migration will surely make you lose page rank, SEO, etc.

Make sure everything is working, make 301 redirects as needed, and backup, backup, backup (one for each stage of the proccess, or for each 3~5 hours of work (if the site isn't huge, of course). To make backups lighter, exclude heavy folders (video/photos/etc) from the hourly backups (make at least one good copy of videos and photos).

Rush will kill your site. In 15 years of web dev&design, I've NEVER saw a sucessful rushed project.

Good luck.